# Nhibernate: Map column that may not exist in database

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there a way to map a column that may or may not exist in database or to map it dynamically to a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically change the mappings but I don't think there is a way to map a column that may or may not exist.  The below example is how you might do it if you were using fluent nhibernate.

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure())
      .Mappings(m =>
          m.FluentMappings
          .AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderMap>()
          .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PascalCaseColumnNameConvention>())
          .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate");

var config = fluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration();

foreach(PersistentClass persistentClass in config.ClassMappings)
{
    //Check to see if there are any missing columns from this mapping.
    //If so remove the column from the mapping.

    //TODO: Query the database and catch errors related to missing columns
    //      If a column is missing remove it
}

var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```